# Why the HR not answering or replying to my emails, after I passed all interview stages?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, germany

Recently was approached in Germany by well-known electric cars manufacturer in Berlin, it is their first factory in Europe and they need construction professionals for the new construction expansion.

They contact me via phone and invited for an interview in Berlin I live in Frankfort so it is a long journey via train. They insisted that I came in person so I booked the train tickets due to end of week cost me 300 euros two ways plus food.

Everything went ok, I reached the factory passed the 3 stages of interview and I was immediately congratulated by the hiring manager, saying: *"welcome you have made it, we will send you the final contract for signature"*. I said fine, I was really happy since this is my first big opportunity in Germany as I need a decent offer above 60K per year to apply for a blue card.

Also, I was clear with them that I am on a study visas, and they said no problem they will sponsor the blue card requirements.

Few days later HR called me and discussed the salary, final offer bonus etc.. and I said fine and she told me please send your train tickets copies so we can endorse you. Next day she emailed me again, asking for documents, degrees insurance all send and I was hopeful.

Then she called back asking for the blue card, I said I told you I have no blue card I need your job offer to apply for it with the auslander in Berlin or Frankfort... 3 weeks passed now and they are not answering emails, phone calls or even SMS... I am really feeling so angry as how can someone treat hopeful candidate in such a way... I emailed asking for the train tickets endorsement but no reply.

Please advice me, 300$ for a student is a lot of money these days, plus the agony and mental stress all adds up... I was clear with them from day 1 that I am on a study visa, and they said no problem they will sponsor the blue card requirements...

Comment: Did you reach out to them in any way before they called you?  If not, how did they acquire your number?  Are you sure this was not some sort of scam?

Comment: No sir, I was interviewed inside the factory, it a very well known electric manufacturer, all legal.i applied for the job opening via LinkedIn

Comment: Do you have in emails/writing the moment where they offered sponsor blue card etc? Or was it all in words?

Comment: Yes sir, I have several emails and texts from the  hr requesting several documents from me to complete the final job contract

Comment: @alexSassa good. keep a copy of them as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Is it a well-known electric car manufacturer that's well-known for having a CEO who might not understand European working practices?

Comment: Yes,  and he is planning to colonize Mars soon

Comment: @alexSassa, Can you try to call or email HR and your recruiter again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's helpful, this is in the form of a written communication you would send to the company. I've tried to build on excellent advice from others you've already received and includes a reference to German law. I would send it and follow up with a call to let them know it's coming. Three weeks is not that long for an overworked HR department to clear an offer, so patience is a virtue, but it is not unreasonable to remind them to be sensitive to your situation as an applicant. Polite persistence often works. Good luck!

Dear (company rep),

Can you please take a moment to provide an update regarding the status of the following two important open issues for me, following my in-person interview at (insert company) on (insert date)?

1. **The verbal employment offer I received from (insert name) for the position of (insert title), directly following my in-person interview**

**Background**
After the interview (insert name) had stated "Welcome, you have made it, we will send you the final contract for signature." At that time I had disclosed the need for sponsorship of my "blue card" and received assurance that this would not be a problem. I was later contacted by (insert name) from HR to provide proof of degrees and required documentation, which I sent via (email? insert date).

**Update request**
Can you please let me know if the offer is still in-progress and if so, at what stage it is? If not, has anything changed in your determination to extend employment? On a personal note, this is important for my continued domicile in Germany to obtain employment in a timely manner (note: if there is a cut off date you may want to include it).

2. **Renumeration to me for expenses related to the above visit, per section 670 of the German Civil Code (Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch)**

**Background**
I have attached all receipts related to my train tickets to and from Frankfort, included meals and associated expenses to facilitate your processing of my refund of (insert amount).

**Update request**
Would you please let me know when I may expect reimbursement in the post? On a personal note, as a student, (insert amount) is a fairly large sum to manage in my monthly budget. If you could provide a check within the next week or so it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much for your attention to my inquiry, especially with all the hiring and other activities you need to accomplish. I will be following up by phone call to make sure you've received all you need.

Kind regards,
(name)

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrgerliches_Gesetzbuch

Comment: This is the more official link:https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2925

Comment: This company does not have a great reputation for following laws. Its sister company with the same CEO is currently being sued by Germany for not following laws. It might be worth adding what to do if the company just ignores the reimbursement request.

Answer (score 8):

> Please advice me, 300$ for a student is a lot of money these days, plus the agony and mental stress all adds up... I was clear with them from day 1 that I am on a study visa, and they said no problem they will sponsor the blue card requirements...

We cannot really tell what happened, or whether you will get this job. Germans are pretty straighforward. We don't ghost people, we just tell you that you won't get the job. So a delay like this can mean about anything or nothing.

If one channel of communication fails, try another. In this case, call them. Be polite, ask what the status of your contract work is. Since they have to pick up the phone to actually find out it's you, they cannot block you. Ask a friend to make the call from their phone if you suspect they do, but I doubt that.

The fact that none of your communication gets a reply might well be because people are out sick or on holidays and this being a new factory, they are not fully staffed yet.

Continue looking for other jobs. That is good general advice anyway. Until you have signed a contract, keep looking.

That said, you are entitled to this reimbursement *by law*. It is not dependent on the outcome. You could have totally bombed the interview and been led out the building by security and you *still* would be entitled to be reimbursed. The only way they don't have to reimburse you is if they had informed you *before* you paid the money that they won't cover the costs. Since they already asked for details to pay you back, I assume they did not do that.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Good points, thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, back in the days when applications were written on paper, companies all the time didn't reply to an application because telling you they didn't choose you may give away why they didn't choose you and that may fall back on them. So they simply don't say anything.

Answer (score 3):

3 weeks with no answer is, to me, enough time for me to worry or raise some flags.

My main suggestion is that you **keep your options open and apply/continue applying to other jobs**, in case this one ghosts you.

Realistically, there are few things you can do for this current process where you are getting no answer (you already reached out in may ways). As I mentioned, the best you can do is carry on and continue job-searching to make best use of your time and resources.

However, I do suggest that if you have anything in writing (email, texts, etc.), where they offered to sponsor blue card/work permit, the train ticket coverage, etc., keep it close or save a copy just to be sure and have it as reference in case they answer back and "forgot" about some of those aspects.

Best of luck with your job-searching!